# save session in database by CodeIgniter

Tags: database, session, codeigniter

I want to save session in database.in CodeIgniter user guide , make an example to store some data in database.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_sessions` (
session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
ip_address varchar(16) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
user_agent varchar(50) NOT NULL,
last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
user_data text DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (session_id)
);
```

Now I want to store an extra data by session in datbase,for example request_token value.

```
$this->session->set_userdata('request_token','test');
```

How should I do it by session?

Comment: A detail blog: http://goo.gl/iSFJ6x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to your config.php under application folder and set use session database option to true. Import the sql structure like you have there and use sessions like you have. It will store the session variable in db. You might want to enable session encryption as well.

Comment: e.g to have rquest_token in db,I should add
request_token varchar(250) to the ci_session table?

Comment: No, you don't need to add any more columns in the DB table. The Session library stores all the userdata as a serialised array in the 'user_data' column.

Comment: will it also persist session that we use without database too? 
e.g $this->session->get_userdata("admin");
will this fetch from database only or the one that we have without database