# how to limit webpage access to 1 user per ip?

Tags: php, javascript, .htaccess, mod-security

is the a way to stop multi-logins to a website to 1 connection/IP ?

let say that my website is http://website.com and i want only 1 user to browse from 1 IP !

is this possible using php, javascript or htaccess ?

i've done many test to htaccess but all failed

thanks in advance

Comment: yes but what about colleges and places that share a common ip?

Comment: Earlier you asked a question about how to determine whether a site was being accessed through an IP that was itself a web server, and whether this could be done in JavaScript. I wrote out an answer for you (the answer is that you need to do it in PHP, but you can pass that boolean to JavaScript) but sadly, I found your question to be deleted. Do be aware that deleting a question can waste people's time. It didn't seem off-topic, but it had garnered one downvote, which you should not worry about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes, but you shouldn't!

Assuming you just want to stop multiple users on one IP address from logging into a typical authentication system, just add two rows to your `users` database table: `last_ip` and `last_seen`.

`last_ip` is updated on each page load if the user's IP address has changed.
`last_seen` is updated on each page load.

When a user submits a login request, check if another user's `last_ip` is equal to the user's IP address and `last_seen` is within a sane time period (say 30 minutes). If so, deny the login request.

### It's a bad idea because it's easily avoided

Using a VPN, TOR or an open proxy, it's very easy for users to operate multiple IP addresses in different browsers or even in different tabs in the same browser.

Also, looking forward to IPv6, it's likely that each user will have 64-256 IP addresses by standard.

### It's also a bad idea because it harms legitimate users

Users in poor countries, multiple people living in the same home, people at colleges or workplaces may well share IPs. A user does not map well to an IP address.

Comment: Yeah, I am wondering what the OP would need to do this for anyways.

Comment: @Mark Probably he's doing something like a voting system, game or competition where he wants to prevent multiple entries from one user.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply,
i'm talking about a simple php page without any database, and i need it exactly to stop people from the same home :)
it's a links download site that have a rule of 1 link every 5 minutes, so i need something to register the ip address used by 1 name and stop them from using another somehow, i know what i'm asking is weird and should be fixed by the link bot php script which i have no idea how to add the single ip function to it :)
thanks again

Comment: @GuestofHonor Same answer, but use a [json](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) / [XML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) config file or [SQLite](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php) daemonless database. Anything else is client side and easily bypassed.

Comment: @GuestofHonor You may want to do other things like creating cookies or using JavaScript localstorage (on top of a server side solution), will go some way to preventing proxy abuse but a determined user will always get around these restrictions *(source: spent far too long trying to enforce one account per user on a game I made)*.

Comment: @SweetieBelle, lol, they are annoying i know, i have users that will login using like 10 names to get all their links, the funny part is that the links i provide are only alive for 3 hours, and they cannot finish 2 or 3 downloads before the TTL is over and they will request a download again, but they just annoy me and i want to find a way to limit this
can you please help me with what you said about limiting proxy access ?
and it would be better if it can be done using javascript cookies code!
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible but it's a bit weird :)
You can save sessions (which also hold the IP address) to the DB, whenever a session is closed/expired - delete it.

If you're using Codeigniter read [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14055282/1057429).
Otherwise, [*here's*](http://culttt.com/2013/02/04/how-to-save-php-sessions-to-a-database/) a nice "walk-through".